# Upload Docs via Email into Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Dear Expers;
I read a feature about of Google docs. (You can see: http://lifehacker.com/217832/upload-google-docs-via-email) 
This article says that google provides a secret email adress for uploading docs. But I could not find this options. How should I look?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

This question probably belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

However, a quick Google search returns http://www.google.gr/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=42b2340630f7844e&hl=en

It actually wasn't a 'secret' e-mail address at all, but apparently the service has been suspended.